# powershell datetime subtraction

Tags: powershell, datetime

I set up variables.

```
$script:current = [datetime]::Today
$r = 120
$global:eastern = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::convertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId([datetime]::Now, 'Eastern Standard Time')
```

How would I go abouts  subtracting seconds from this oneliner?

```
    $variable = (($script:current.DayOfWeek -match 'Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday') -and $global:eastern.hour -eq 09 -and $global:eastern.Minute -eq 30 -and ([datetime]::Now.Second -eq 0))
```

This works, but trying to do so without an 'overload parsexact' error

```
    $culture = [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture
    $format  = 'HH:mm:ss'
    $east = [datetime]::ParseExact('09:30:00',$culture,'AssumeUniversal, AdjustToUniversal').Addseconds(-$r) 
    [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId($east, 'Eastern Standard Time')
```

Comment: Also, take care that `ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId()` returns a date with `.Kind` property set to `Unspecified` whilst `[datetime]::Today` returns a date with property Kind set to `Local`. This potentially _could_ present problems. See the Remarks section on [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimebysystemtimezoneid)

Comment: OK. thank you for your time.  That clears it up!

Comment: Solution:
    $culture = [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture
    $format  = 'HH:mm:ss'
    $east = [datetime]::Parse('09:30:00').Addseconds(-$script:TotalTime) 
    [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId($east, 'Eastern Standard Time')

Answer (score 1):

The overload error you're getting on [`.ParseExact(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-6.0#system-datetime-parseexact(system-string-system-string-system-iformatprovider-system-globalization-datetimestyles)) method is because you're missing the **string Format** argument:

```
$r = 120
$culture = [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture
$format  = 'HH:mm:ss'
$styles = [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]'AssumeUniversal, AdjustToUniversal'
[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(
    [datetime]::ParseExact('09:30:00', $format, $culture, $styles).Addseconds(-$r),
    'Eastern Standard Time'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, subtracting 2 minutes and returning a new [datetime]:

```
get-date; (get-date) - [timespan]'0:2:0'

Sunday, January 23, 2022 11:31:40 AM
Sunday, January 23, 2022 11:29:40 AM
```

Comment: Yes, very close.
$r = 120 seconds
Ultimately I'm trying to get "9:30:00 Eastern standard time" - [timespan]$r

Comment: Ok I made it 2 minutes.